# how to get rid of the space between first and second element? and how to create a "if" statement for selecting information?

Tags: python-2.7

19.7435
,5281813.4260,536064.1543,0.371886,out04-36-48-12.tif

```
lines = f.readlines()
    for items in lines:
        items = items.replace("\n", "")
        #print items
        new_file = items.split(",")
        new_list_project = ','.join(new_file)
        new_list_project = new_list_project.rstrip()
        print new_list_project
```

it always looks like this, but i already used rstrip to remove \n.

```
19.7435
,5281813.4260,536064.1543,0.371886,out04-36-48-12.tif
```

also i wanted to select the last element based upon the value of third (0.371886). i write statement but none of them working. 
This list has 2000 elements. I might be use for and if statement i guess.

Comment: Add your file content.

Comment: It was some content from that list. Elevation, Easting, Northing, Blur metric, Imagery 
19.8091
,5281850.4252,536047.6051,0.335554,out04-32-44-03.tif

19.8256
,5281850.5974,536047.2831,0.337232,out04-32-44-15.tif

19.8420
,5281850.7696,536046.9611,0.4184,out04-32-44-27.tif

19.8584
,5281850.9418,536046.6392,0.311989,out04-32-44-39.tif

Comment: ['19.8299', '5281812.6463', '536062.9496', '0.352234', 'out04-36-47-52.tif']
I wanted to select the "out04-36-" element based upon the value of third element. so i write scrip like this ,but only the first "if "statement is working.if file_reverse[3] > 0.4:
           print file_reverse[4] + "\t" + "blurry"
           
        if (file_reverse[3] > 0.3 and file_reverse[3] < 0.4) :
           print file_reverse[4] + "\t" + "moderately blurry"
        
        if file_reverse[3] < 0.3:
           print file_reverse[4] +"\t" + "clear"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to remove \n after  the words. The following code should do it.

```
f = open("sample.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
for items in lines:
    items = [item.strip() for item in items.split(",")]
    if items[3] == "0.371886":
        print ",".join(items)
    else:
        print "Whatever you want"
```

Assuming your file content is:

```
Elevation, Easting, Northing, Blur metric, Imagery
19.8091 ,5281850.4252,536047.6051,0.335554,out04-32-44-03.tif
19.7435 ,5281813.4260,536064.1543,0.371886,out04-36-48-12.tif
19.8256 ,5281850.5974,536047.2831,0.337232,out04-32-44-15.tif
19.8420 ,5281850.7696,536046.9611,0.4184,out04-32-44-27.tif
19.8584 ,5281850.9418,536046.6392,0.311989,out04-32-44-39.tif
```

Output:

```
Whatever you want
Whatever you want
19.7435,5281813.4260,536064.1543,0.371886,out04-36-48-12.tif
Whatever you want
Whatever you want
Whatever you want
```

Comment: Thanks it works now and i m moving to the next step.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove the space between first and second element

Try this :

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    print("".join([i.replace(' ','') for i in f]))
```

I assumed your data is in a file called "file.txt" .

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It remove the space between first and last element , I don't know what is the point of downvoting .

Comment: I did not downvote but your answer is up for removal. You only blurted out code without explanation. That is not what SO is for. Do not post any explanation to me. Post it in your answer!